# Set limit of number of nodes in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've 10 worker nodes (machines) in my spark cluster.

I want to run my one spark job only on 4 worker nodes out of 10. Is there any way I could set it to run my program only on 4 worker nodes ?

Comment: I think you can pass `--num-executors 4` to `spark-submit`; how are you running your job?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Number of executors are not worker nodes but number of JVM processes in a worker node.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I don't have my own cluster up right now but why do you want to do this? And are you using open source spark or cloudera? I ask because [static service pools](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cm_mc_service_pools.html) may not be open source.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, some jobs I just want to run on limited number of worker nodes only.

Comment: As far as i know, ter are options only to limit the number of executors not nodes. I guess that is a part of the design.